# Is it possible to hide a tab from a group of users in Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a tab (Internal Development Review) on one of my work item forms that I would not like to show to all users:

[image]

Is it possible to hide this from a specific user group (or conversely, to grant it to another group)? I cannot find a way to put permissions on a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I sort of took care of this. I added an EMPTY rule to the field and set Not: to my Senior Developer group, which does not hide the tab but disables and shows no information in the text box. This more or less does what I want it to (although I'd rather hide the tab altogether).

Answer (score 1):

We did it by using the Target attribute in the Layout tag. The developers use the interface that is integrated in VS2010, the testers use the web portal. We removed all unnecessary tabs from the web interface.

Comment: Good idea, but we already use the web portal for a different group as well. It turns out to not be as big of a deal as it seemed when the original requirements were gathered, so disabling the text box was good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Example: <FORM><Layout Target="WinForms"> ... </Layout><Layout Target="Web"> ... </Target></FORM>